# How to fix Imported SVG from inkscape with wrong fill

Tags: svg

I have imported this image from inkscape SVG. One of the characters have wrong fill in the letter. I am fairly new to blender. Is it possible to fix it?

[image: Blender]
[image: Inkscape]

Comment: This is the SVG file that is used in this case: [https://expirebox.com/download/4160aa684cea31831846ba9e69db61ea.html](https://expirebox.com/download/4160aa684cea31831846ba9e69db61ea.html)

Comment: Remove any duplicate segments or overlapping vertex

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your drawing, the SVG file is not properly sanitized, there are overlapping segments and residual segments in your spline

There is a small circle overlapping the inner part of your R letter, it is causing letter fill rendering to fail.

See [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/52875#52875) for more details