# Create 3D world map from .svg file

Tags: import, svg

So I'm trying to create a flat 3D world map from a .svg file which I grabbed from this site: https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/169563-vector-3d-global-world-map

I've imported it to Blender and did some research on how to create a 3D object from this by filling with shape. However, it does not fill all the countries only a bit on the top and I am wondering what's wrong?

This is how it looks (when the "curve" layer is not seen, note there are two layers "curve" and "curve.001" if you try this yourself):

[image: Current look]

I'm also wondering if it would be possible to create each country into it's own 3D object?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because a huge amount of self-intersections:
[image]
and lots of vertex(100 thousand). So you need to simplify this map, or maybe, find a map that less complex?

So, to manage this task, I use Inkscape, as a svg editor.

1. In Inkscape go through groups by doble-clicking on map while status bar will say, that you selected the curve.
2. Next - simplify curve <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or in menu **Curve**
3. Next, beat a self-intersections. Break apart curve by <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd> (menu **Object**) and Boolean union  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>  (menu **Object**)
4. Finally, export in blender. After operations in Inkscape, object still buggy:

[image]

but in my case, there is only 3 places with intersections, that I need to fix:

[image]

Just move one vertex a little bit:

[image]

Or delete:

[image]

And how to find those dots:

[image]

Search for very top point where model starts to go wrong.