# Importing SVG squiggle inverts half the image

Tags: mesh, import

Anyone have any tips for solving this SVG import of a drawn squiggle, that I'd like to turn into a pipe mesh?
Here's the original and the blender import. You'll see the bottom half doesn't go quite to plan!
thanks

ORIGINAL
[image]

BLENDER screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, the problem is in [intersections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97206/create-3d-world-map-from-svg-file).

Try to fix this using  Simplify Curves+.

Enable it is preferences.

[image]

When go to edit mode, select all points and in context menu select **Remove by distance**

When adjust the result using F9