# Curve from svg file has dissimilarities to original vector

Tags: bezier-curves, import, svg

I am trying to import [this svg file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ywugbnQmmpB9xcbJGsxqa0To0QnT1tIO/view?usp=sharing) but the curve which comes out as a result has a lot of dissimilarities to the original vector. 
[image: Look of original vector]

[image: Curve in Blender]

Can anyone tell what's happening here? I'm sorry if the answer seems obvious, I'm still quite new to blender.

Comment: Could you post a link to the svg file?. The link above opens as  a png.

Comment: Almost certain your curve has [duplicate vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve), overlapping geometry, [duplicate segments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill) or all of the above

Comment: Ah, thought it was the svg file I shared. It should be working now. @batFINGER

Comment: alright, I'll try to clean up the vector, see how it goes