# Curve fill is clipping from Illustrator SVG export

Tags: bezier-curves

Can't figure out why the fill in this imported SVG "k" curve is clipping like this. Other letters in the same import are filling fine even with islands but two letters are clipping like this. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Most likely you are dealing with disconnected points on the curve amking it an open curve.

Comment: You might need to do some cleanup on the imported path. read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve/47220#47220 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/52875#52875

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Imported SVG from inkscape with wrong fill](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extrude and bevel an imported svg curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve)

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being that I needed to change the "decimal" input to a value of 1 in the SVG export options in Illustrator.