# Why is my Xerox font degrading in appearance in Blender?

Tags: text-object

I was gonna make a Xerox logo remake in Blender, but the letters and et cetera were degraded and their pixels were invisible. How must we fix this??!

[image: Whoever made and published that font had better fix that issue now. 'Cause if he made the font unsuitable for Blender, he had better shame himself.]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered/

Comment: maybe you need to finish the work and fill the faces in Edit mode

Comment: Maybe I could download an SVG of the Xerox logo and put it in Blender. The only Xerox logos I can do now are the ones from 1968 and 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts are known for topology issues and **this one** is, too, incontinuous (see below)
[image]

Maybe Blender has problems qualifying it as a separate object or a hole or yet something else and hence the incomplete filling.

One way out of this is to make the logo in an external app and import it as a plane to Blender. Then, just set the camera to ortographic, add proper world color and you're done.

Or, if you want to do some more Blender work, use it as a background image for your model.