# Joining SVG curves into one object loses faces

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

when joining SVG curves into one object I am losing faces.  How do I avoid or add the face back in
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825