# Blender .svg importer dispays curves in incorrect Order

Tags: 3d-view, bezier-curves, render-layers

Why does the .svg Blender editor display the imported curves in the exact opposite order of the original svg-file, unless I set the *Shadeless* property on their materials and switch to *Rendered* viewport-shading?

At first I thought this is a very special error but in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OceWzEFhTdQ) he has got the same issue.

Notice the white circle in the middle get's displayed behind the arrows in blender. Then he bothers about the colors and in the end changes everything to *Shadeless*, renders and gets the right result.

Isn't that kind of a bug?

Well at least now I that I found a solution to my problem, but maybe this could get fixed, since I wasted half a day on that confusing display-issue...

Comment: I have to correct this, the "shadeless property" is not necessary to render it in the correct order.

Comment: There is no "order" in displaying objects in a 3D scene. SVG files are 2D elements when imported into a 3D scene they will be overlapping at Z=0, which leads to [Z-Fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) artifacts

Comment: Also see related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/svg-curve-incorrectly-rendered